# Is it possible to get the area of a fill in a postscript object?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I'm currently extracting the colors of an .eps file via a .ps program. I'm trying to figure out how much each color is being used in the .eps file. Is it possible to get the area, or some measurement of the fill shape so I know how much the color is used overall in the .eps file?

My current solution is to rasterize the image and parse the histogram, but I'm trying to do this with the vector file.

Comment: Rasterizing is probably the cheapest solution: overlaps, clips, splines, fonts - all of it would have to be taken into account...

Comment: the fill operator simply fills a path. The path may be arbitrarily complex, including curves and may not be continuous. If you are prepared to do the calculation yourself then you can use currentpath to return the path which will be filled. I still don't understand what your goal is here. Why do you need to find the coverage in the original colour space ?

Comment: My goal is to understand the most used colors by area (not by object count) of the .eps file.

Comment: Depending on the source of the eps, there may be (a lot of) overpainting in the drawing commands. Even processing the path yourself (which sounds really hard) may deliver wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start investigating this, here's a replacement for `fill` which will dump the path contents to stdout.

```
/={=only( )print}def
/oldfill /fill load def
/fill {
    gsave
        clip
        clippath
        { exch = = (moveto\n)print }
        { exch = = (lineto\n)print }
        { 6 -1 1 { -1 roll = } for (curveto\n)print }
        { (closepath\n)print }
        pathforall
    grestore
    oldfill
} def
```